# session id not changing on session time out in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4

in my web config the code is

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" cookieless="false" timeout="10"  customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
```

and global.asax file

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       Session["init"] = 0;          
 }

protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         Session.Clear();
 }
```

the problem is to generate new session id after session timeout even if the browser and client machine instance is same.

and with code above it is maintaining the same session id even after session time out.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your session ID is maintained within ASP.NET session ID cookie. Doing Session.Clear() is not sufficient, you actually have to remove cookie from the response itself.

To do that, set expiration on cookie to negative value, such as -1.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```